# How do I maintain a $this reference across two classes in different scripts?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

ok, that's a bit odd but here's the situation:

I am working in an MVC context

I have a User class used as a library(User.php)

ANd then I have a controller class that handles input from the user(controller.php)

Here's how it goes:

1. user registers
2. registerhandler() is called in controller
3. registerhandler() calls register() method in User class
4. register() method creates a User instance with $this and returns a token and echoes a message linking to a verifyhandler() in controller class
5. verifyhandler calls verify() method in User class
6. verify() method uses $this to reference the User instance created by register()
7. boom! $this is not pointing to the same object(created by register() method ) anymore!

I want to maintain that reference yet it seems to take on another value once it is passed to the controller. What can I do about it?

Comment: Can you please post some code samples? Have you tried passing your object by reference? E.g function foo(&$var) vs function foo($var)?

Comment: I am currently editing the code so I cannot post anything right now. Guess I will just go with passing objects by reference but that would mean a major change so I'm trying to work with a $this right now.

Answer (score 2):

`$this` always points to the class instance it is used. So `$this` in your controller and your library will always point to something different and there is little you can do about it.

What you can do is to change the definition of a register function that it accept parameter you want to work with and reference to this parameter instead of using `$this`. The other option is to define a field in your class and use that field for reference, this way all class methods can be work on the same object.

I think this is more less you want to achieve.

```
class UserController {
    // User library instance
    private $User = new User();

    private $token = null;

    public function registerhandler() {
        $this->token = $this->User->register();
    }

    private function verifyhandler() {
        $valid = $this->User->verify($this->token);
        ...
    }
}

class User {
    private $sharedData;
    public function register() {
        // register all common data in $sharedData property
        ...
        return $token;
    }

    public function verify($token) {
        // use shared data and method input to verify the data
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the answer I'm looking for...I was spending hours in working with a workaround since I was trying to convert an auth script made without a framework to Kohana and then this propblem came in. Guess I have to use references an recreate the whole class; thanks RaYell!

Comment: If this is an acceptable answer to you, click the accept tick thingy.